# how to set default document in web.config file in ASP.NET MVC application..?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, model-view-controller

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC application it is working fine now i want to host it on IIS server, I'm doing this as generic procedure when I'm opening it on browser that time it showing all directories list what now how can set my default action  in web.config file.

Answer (score 1):

You don't set a default document with MVC. There's no such thing as documents in MVC, let alone a default one. If you're getting a directory listing instead of your app being loaded, then there's some problem with your setup. Most likely, you don't have it as an actual application in IIS, but just a virtual directory

Comment: i have hosted my MVC application on IIS now when i'm opening this site that time it showing all the files what i include in virtual directory, i have already set default Controller and Action in route.config file. when i'm executing this project working perfectly in case of opening IIS site it is not working